# Shouldn't these two characters have been eliminated?

Tags: plot-explanation, circle

In the movie [Circle (2015)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3118452/?ref_=rvi_tt) a group of people have been abducted and find themselves standing in a dark room standing each on a red circle and quickly learn that they are being forced to play a game of elimination. Some of the rules they quickly discern are that if you leave your circle you will be automatically eliminated and also if you touch anyone else you will be eliminated.

There is a slight twist at the end when the last standing character learns that

> the baby inside the pregnant lady's stomach counts as one of the players.

If this is true then shouldn't the pregnant lady and the baby have been eliminated as soon as the game began?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motivations of the film's antagonists are intentionally unclear, so it's impossible to say for certain.

The argument could be made that it's the *act* of touching someone that incurs the penalty, so those two characters were already touching when the game began and thus didn't suffer any penalty.  They also didn't leave their circle, so they never broke any rules.

Comment: Yeah I supposed that could be an explanation for it.